# Making GET API call to Twitter using Access Token and Access Secret

Tags: api, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am testing this in Postman. Calling GET [link](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=xxxxxxx)

I am using Firebase auth to OAuth login using twitter. This allows me obtain user `access token` and `access secret`.

I wanted to make an API call in the client to retrieve current users statuses on user timeline. however  by just `access token` and `access secret` I get an `400` error status with `code 215`(bad auth data). If I include app `consumer key` and `consumer secret` the API GET request works. But this limits me to make the call on my server because the consumer secret is exposed. Is this the only way? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need all 4, otherwise the access token/secret can be stolen and anyone can access that account on your behalf.
So your calls need to be like this:

Client => Server => Twitter

Twitter=> Server => Client